# Prolog: Getting certain elements in a list

Tags: prolog

I am trying to find first and last element of a list such that lastFirstElt(X, L)  outputs list L which contains only first and last element. I am able to get first and last element and I was trying to combine this into a list L that contains only first and last element but I somehow can't make it work:

```
first(X, [X|_]). % to get first element
last(X, [X]).% last element if it is only one
last(X,[_|T]) :- last(X,T). % otherwise recurs to the last 
lastFirstElt(X, L):- first(X,L), last(X,L). % Here, I was expecting the first and last element will be joined into List L
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lastFirstElt(X, L):- first(X,L), last(X,L).
```

Here, you are saying that the result of `first`, the result of `last` and the result of `lastFirstElt` are the same value, namely `X`.

This is what you want instead:

```
lastFirstElt([First, Last], L):- first(First,L), last(Last,L).
```